# what is the better alternative to following if-else ladder in java?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, optimization

**Situation :** I am examining filenames , the filename is stored in a `String` variable called `str` and according to the conditions checked in `if` statements i am setting the value of a variable called `mailType` .

```
if(str.contains("template"))
        {                   
          if(str.contains("unsupported"))
              mailType="unsupported";      
              else
                  if(str.contains("final_result"))                
                      mailType="final_result";            
                  else
                      if(str.contains("process_success"))
                          mailType="Process Success"; 
                      else
                          if(str.contains("receive"))                         
                              mailType="Receive";                         
                          else
                          if(str.contains("sen"))
                              mailType="sent"; 
                          else
                              if(str.contains("welcome"))
                                  mailType="welcome";
                              else
                                  if(str.contains("manual"))
                                     mailType="Manual";                    
        }       
        else                
if(str.contains("properties"))
        {

          if(str.contains("unsupported"))
              mailType="unsupported";      
              else
                  if(str.contains("final_result"))                
                      mailType="final_result";            
                  else
                      if(str.contains("process_success"))
                          mailType="Process Success"; 
                      else
                          if(str.contains("receive"))                         
                              mailType="Receive";                         
                          else
                          if(str.contains("sen"))
                              mailType="sent"; 
                          else
                              if(str.contains("welcome"))
                                  mailType="welcome";
                              else
                                  if(str.contains("manual"))
                                     mailType="Manual";

        }
```

**Problem :** Is there any better way to do this in java that shortens my code and is memory friendly ?

Comment: Your code would be much more readable if you used `if else` rather than `else` (with no braces) and indent the subsequent block.

Comment: Just making Andy's point: http://pastie.org/10798591 or better yet http://pastie.org/10798593

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for adding those!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder funny thing, there's no ladder with proper formatting and the answer becomes obvious.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use a `LinkedHashMap<String, String>`:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> mapping = new LinkedHashMap<>();
mapping.put("unsupported", "unsupported");
mapping.put("final_result", "final_result");
// ... etc
```

Then iterate the map until you find a matching key:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mapping.entrySet()) {
  if (str.contains(entry.getKey()) {
    mailType = entry.getValue();
    break;
  }
}
```

The key point here is that `LinkedHashMap` preserves insertion order (unlike `HashMap`) so you can actually specify the order in which you want to test for matches (other map implementations do this too, e.g. Guava's `ImmutableMap`; `LinkedHashMap` is simply one that you have out of the box).

If you need to nest this for the outer cases, you can simply apply the same pattern:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>> outerMapping =
    new LinkedHashMap<>();
outerMapping.put("template", mapping);
outerMapping.put("properties", someOtherMapping);
```

And then just iterate through the keys in the same way:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>> outerEntry : outerMapping.entrySet()) {
  if (str.contains(outerEntry.getKey()) {
    // Apply the iteration above, using outerEntry.getValue().
  }
}
```

Comment: No offense but i find this approach a bit complex , since i am a beginner could you suggest something else ? Moreover this approach will take more memory right ?

Comment: @varunsinghal the approach you choose depends upon what you want to optimize for. This is just one approach; I can see why you might consider it complex as a beginner. It is quite good if you want to be able to specify the mappings dynamically (e.g. in an external config); as they say, YMMV :)

Comment: @varunsinghal: The above will use only a truly trivial amount more memory, nothing to worry about. It's also very easy to maintain, and really not at all complicated. FWIW, it's what I'd do, or something very similar to it.

Answer (score 2):

You've said you find [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36643407/157247) (which is what I'd do) too complex. His [original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643356/what-is-the-better-alternative-to-following-if-else-ladder-in-java/36643833#comment60880432_36643356) suggesting `else if` may be an option for you:

```
if (str.contains("template")) {
    if (str.contains("unsupported"))
        mailType = "unsupported";
    else if (str.contains("final_result"))
        mailType = "final_result";
    else if (str.contains("process_success"))
        mailType = "Process Success";
    else if (str.contains("receive"))
        mailType = "Receive";
    else if (str.contains("sen"))
        mailType = "sent";
    else if (str.contains("welcome"))
        mailType = "welcome";
    else if (str.contains("manual"))
        mailType = "Manual";
} else if (str.contains("properties")) {
    if (str.contains("unsupported"))
        mailType = "unsupported";
    else if (str.contains("final_result"))
        mailType = "final_result";
    else if (str.contains("process_success"))
        mailType = "Process Success";
    else if (str.contains("receive"))
        mailType = "Receive";
    else if (str.contains("sen"))
        mailType = "sent";
    else if (str.contains("welcome"))
        mailType = "welcome";
    else if (str.contains("manual"))
        mailType = "Manual";
}
```

or better yet, with consistent use of {}:

```
if (str.contains("template")) {
    if (str.contains("unsupported")) {
        mailType = "unsupported";
    } else if (str.contains("final_result")) {
        mailType = "final_result";
    } else if (str.contains("process_success")) {
        mailType = "Process Success";
    } else if (str.contains("receive")) {
        mailType = "Receive";
    } else if (str.contains("sen")) {
        mailType = "sent";
    } else if (str.contains("welcome")) {
        mailType = "welcome";
    } else if (str.contains("manual")) {
        mailType = "Manual";
    }
} else if (str.contains("properties")) {
    if (str.contains("unsupported")) {
        mailType = "unsupported";
    } else if (str.contains("final_result")) { 
        mailType = "final_result";
    } else if (str.contains("process_success")) {
        mailType = "Process Success";
    } else if (str.contains("receive")) {
        mailType = "Receive";
    } else if (str.contains("sen")) {
        mailType = "sent";
    } else if (str.contains("welcome")) {
        mailType = "welcome";
    } else if (str.contains("manual")) { 
        mailType = "Manual";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
static String containsAndValue(Collection<String> collection, String oldValue, String... strings) {
    if (strings.length % 2 != 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("strings");
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i += 2)
        if (collection.contains(strings[i]))
            return strings[i + 1];
    return oldValue;
}
```

and

```
if (str.contains("template")) {
    mailType = containsAndValue(str, mailType,
        "unsupported", "unsupported",
        "final_result", "final_result",
        "process_success", "Process Success",
        "receive", "Receive",
        "sen", "sent",
        "welcome", "welcome",
        "manual", "Manual");
} else if (str.contains("properties")) {
    mailType = containsAndValue(str, mailType,
        "unsupported", "unsupported",
        "final_result", "final_result",
        "process_success", "Process Success",
        "receive", "Receive",
        "sen", "sent",
        "welcome", "welcome",
        "manual", "Manual");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this less complex?

```
public enum MailType {
    UNSUPPORTED("unsupported", "unsupported"),
    FINAL_RESULT("final_result", "final_result"),
    PROCESS_SUCCESS("process_success", "Process Success"),
    RECEIVE("receive", "Receive"),
    SENT("sen", "sent"),
    WELCOME("welcome", "welcome"),
    MANUAL("manual", "Manual");

    private final String query;
    private final String value;

    MailType(String query, String value) {
        this.query = query;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static String find(String text){
        for(MailType mailType: values()){
            if(text.contains(mailType.query)) {
                return mailType.value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
String mailType = MailType.find(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you use `else if`instead of simple `else`, you will have less indentation.

```
if(str.contains("unsupported"))
          mailType="unsupported";      
else if(str.contains("final_result"))                
          mailType="final_result";            
else if(str.contains("process_success"))
          mailType="Process Success"; 
else if(str.contains("receive"))                         
          mailType="Receive";                         
else if(str.contains("sen"))
          mailType="sent"; 
else if(str.contains("welcome"))
          mailType="welcome";
else if(str.contains("manual"))
          mailType="Manual";
```

In your particular case, i would suggest to try to use regular expression to simplify a bit your work :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(unsupported|final_result|welcome)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.matches()) {
    mailType = m.group(1);
}
```

Comment: The regex approach doesn't quite work - some of the `mailType`s are not the same as what is matched (e.g. `process_success` => `Process Success`).

Comment: Yes, but at least it can help to remove some of the if statements.
In case of a string processing, i try to use regex when i can as it is the appropriate tool.

Comment: "i try to use regex when i can as it is the appropriate tool" You've clearly never heard the ["Now you have two problems"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems) quote :)

Comment: And I don't think it really does help - you then just end up having to create a mapping from "what you found by the regex" to the corresponding value. Then you end up basically back at my solution.