# Too many if statements in JAVA

Tags: java, oop

Hello I'm trying to make a java program where a user can enter different commands and this class can identify all the commands and based on that it calls methods from 3-4 different classes. currently for each command I have different if statements as such:

```
if (input.equals("change category FOOD"){...}
if (input.equals("Sort by price FOOD"){...}
if (input.equals("logout"){...}
```

There are so many commands, and I wanted to know if there is a way to shorten this up.

Comment: Probably. You'd need to give us some idea what is in the `{...}` sections.

Comment: You could use a `switch/case` statement.  Or some kind of Command Pattern where the commands are in a `HashMap`.

Comment: Use a `Map<String, [something]>` to define a mapping between commands and objects representing what to do (the `[something]` part).  Since you haven't told us what the commands are we can't tell you what `something` might be.

Comment: Depending upon what the `...`s are, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643356/what-is-the-better-alternative-to-following-if-else-ladder-in-java/36643407) might give you some pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all, you're checking through every if statement, every single time you're handling input. Use if/else if to keep your code cleaner and more efficient

```
if (input.equals("Hi") { 
... 
}
else if (input.equals("Hi") { 
...
}
```

and so on.

You're also asking for the input to exactly match semi-long strings. This almost never happens in practice and you should either ask for shorter arguments, split the string into an array by using

```
String newString = string.split(" ");
```

Last thing, just try to keep your code as clean as possible. It's likely that you won't be able to shorten your checks, so just keep your code readable and don't put huge blocks of code in one place.

Comment: why would you -1 this...?

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Map<String,Function>`

Set the String key as the command and a [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) as appropriate.

You can then execute the function by calling it from the map.

Comment: i'll give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have proposed using a `map` which is certainly viable. It has a couple of potential disadvantages however:

- you are forever limited to `equals` to match commands to actions
- you will need a singleton map
- can be difficult to test - e.g. mocking the command means exposing the singleton

A possible alternate way to encapsulate a set of commands is using an `enum` with a runnable variable. For example:

```
public enum Command {
    CHANGE_CATEGORY("change category", () -> {
        // change category
    }),
    SORT_BY_PRICE("sort by price", () -> {
        // sort by price
    }),
    ...
    DEFAULT("", () -> {
        // default action
    });

    private final String commandText;
    private final Runnable action;

    Command(String commandText, Runnable action) {
        this.commandText = commandText;
        this.action = action;
    }

    public static void run(String text) {
        Arrays.stream(values())
            .filter(c -> c.commandText.equals(text))
            .findAny().orElse(DEFAULT)
            .action.run();
    }
}
```

This is used as: `Command.run(text)`

This allows you to put all logic associated with the commands in one place and makes it easy to change the logic for matching text (e.g. ignore spaces, case) by changing the filter. This enum is also a singleton but the language is handling all the complexity of when to initialise it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a switch statement with a string automatically implements the string.equals method:

```
    switch(input) {
        case "change category FOOD":
           statement;
           break;
        case "Sort by price FOOD":
           statement;
           break;
        case "logout":
           statement;
           break;
        default:
           statement;
     }
```

Where 'statement' represents the {...} you put in your question.

This is a nice alternative when your if/else statements start piling up. Don't forget to add the `default:` case. It acts as a final 'else' statement in the case that none of the cases are met.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Jim Garrison's comment,

Use a Map, where the first type is the string, representing the command, and the second type is a class which you can run. If you do not need any commands, then use Runnable, and write a Runnable implementation for each command, and in a setup function create the map entries.

If you need more infomation, create n interface SomeInterface which has a method onCommand(...), passing the neccessary data. Again, add an implementation for each command, and add each mapping of command to command-runner to the map. Thus, running the correct command implementation would just be

map.get("command").onCommand(...);

Comment: I've tried that, but that would mean it would create that many classes, and there are soo many commands, thus soo many classes as well

Comment: So, you have to go through every command one way or another. Regardless of the method, fundamentally at some point you will be going through some number of possible commands checking each string. All you can do is try to make it more readable for yourself. Separating into classes is a fairly readable means of this, but really it is your coding style that is the deciding factor.

Comment: oh okay thank you so much!